# Implement Java Interface in a Groovy class

Tags: java, groovy

I have just started the programming in Groovy.
I noticed one strange behavior and unable to find any explanation for the same.

**I have created a Java Interface TestInterface.java**

```
public interface TestInterface {

    public void m1();

}
```

**I have created a Groovy class TestG.groovy**

```
class TestG implements TestInterface {

}
```

**I have created a Java class  TestJ.java**

```
public class TestJ implements TestInterface{

    @Override
    public void m1() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    } 
}
```

My problem is in TestG why I do not get any error to implement abstract method or declare class as abstract.

What does differ in java and groovy as I needed to implement abstract methods or declare class as abstract in Java but not in Groovy.

Comment: `Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'TestG' must be declared abstract or the method 'void m1()' must be implemented.` this is the error i get running your code. there is no difference to java in that regard.

Comment: What editor are you using? Also, what do you see when you attempt to compile? I would assume that it would throw an exception at compile time as @cfrick found.

Comment: I am using Netbeans on Ubuntu.I am getting a compile time error.But there are no glyph errors i.e. red mark beside the code.

Comment: so the question basically is: why does netbeans not support groovy properly?

Comment: Actually after compiling I got the error, previously I thought that Groovy allows abstract method in a non-abstract class.But now after compilation I am able to see that error which was supposed to marked red at the time of coding.So why it did not  show any glyph for Groovy ?

Comment: from excessive use of intellij i can say, that for each single language (in)officially supported (except maybe java) it shows me false positives and hides real errors.  i bet it's all the same for all the other IDEs. if you think, that this is a problem with netbeans (or the groovy plugin) you should contact the maintainer, file a bug, etc.

Comment: I have some discomfort with Groovy/Eclipse integration too. messages one line below/above etc ...  (but not have evident errors). Language is dynamic with independent compiler, maybe hard to integrate, I forgive :)

Comment: To clear some things up. Groovy has its own compiler, the JVM forbids a non-abstract class with an abstract method, so the Groovy compiler must complain or the JVM will not let it pass verification. The groovy-eclipse compiler is a hybrid between the groovy compiler and JDT. But JDT is not very open to anything that is not Java and the developers don't really want to bother about other languages too much. This means the integration is difficult, but without this you won't get for example refactoring.

Comment: And finally there are sometimes bugs in the line number information in the Groovy compiler. groovy-eclipse tries to fix some of those, but may not for all. And sometimes the what line number makes sense is different for the normal Groovy compiler and eclipse too.

Comment: Java code in Eclipse+Groovy extyension (wrong) `List<int> ll = null;`   -> "insert dimension to complete reference type. Convert to groovy and open in Groovy editor"

Comment: I use JetBrains IntelliJ IDE Community edition is far better for project with java and groovy sources and it does complain for error for `TestG` groovy class if method is not added as other members say.

Answer (score 12):

I know this question has been out for a while and answered above but I felt the need to add this.

```
class TestG implements TestInterface {}
```

this is still the "java" way of doing things. Using groovy essentially eliminates the need of implementing interfaces (except just as markup interfaces)

In groovy you would just do this:

```
def myObject = [m1: {-> doSomething()}] as TestInterface
```